# Quarkus oidc - getting userInfo as JWT

Tags: openid-connect, quarkus

I use the quarkus-oidc for communicate with keycloak. When this library calls the userInfo endpoint, a have exception because the library expect the json response, but keycloak sends response as signed JWT: like this: https://connect2id.com/products/server/docs/api/userinfo.
How can I tweak the quarkus-oidc for getting userInfo as JWT?